# Trying to parse xml with nokogiri and ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to parse the xml below to get the email address out. I can get the messageid but I think having the a: in front is enabling me to use xpath. Not sure how to pull out the email address. I am trying

xml.xpath("//s:Body/Discover/request/EmailAddress").children.text.to_s

and

xml.xpath("//s:Body/Discover/EmailAddress").children.text.to_s

if i do xml.xpath("//s:Body").children.text.to_s i get the email and the version with all the newlines and tabs but i do not want to parse the email out if i do not have to.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> 
    <s:Header> 
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">test url</a:Action> 
        <a:MessageID>mid</a:MessageID> 
        <a:ReplyTo> 
            <a:Address>test url</a:Address> 
        </a:ReplyTo> 
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">test url</a:To> 
    </s:Header> 
    <s:Body> 
        <Discover xmlns="test url"> 
            <request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
                <EmailAddress>bob@xml.com</EmailAddress> 
                <RequestVersion>1.0</RequestVersion> 
            </request> 
        </Discover> 
    </s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: https://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb I found ox 5 times faster than nokogiri, hence here one example in ox - https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431, search for any element and get it in hash form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test url` is preventing Nokogiri's Xpath from catching on to your namespacing within `s:Body`. Try simply

```
 email = xml.xpath("//s:Body").first.to_xml.scan(/<EmailAddress>([^<]+)/)[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Discover` element (and its children) are in a different namespace, and you need to specify this in your query. The second argument to the [`xpath` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) is a hash where you can associate prefixes used in the query with namespace urls. Have a look at the [section on namespaces in the Nokogiri tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces).

With Nokogiri, if you don’t specify a namespace hash it will automatically register any namespaces defined on the root node for you. In this case that is the `a` prefix for `http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing` and the `s` prefix for `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`. This is why your query for `//s:Body` works. The namespace declaration for `Discover` isn’t on the root, so you have to register it yourself.

When you provide your own namespace hash Nokogiri doesn’t add those defined on the root, so you will also need to include any of those used in your query.

In your case the following will find the `EmailAddress` node. The actual prefix you used doesn’t matter (here I’ve chosen `t`) as long as the URI matches).

```
xml.xpath('//s:Body/t:Discover/t:request/t:EmailAddress',
    's' => "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
    't' => "test url")
```